# android development small error

Tags: java, android

hi guys I'm trying to add a splash image within new splash class

but im getting the error : 
    `splash cannot be resolved or is not a field`

the image is already there in drawable-hdpi folder in lower case as png extension

my program is

```
package com.sc.uploader;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle IloveU) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(IloveU);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
}



}
```

I think everything is good but I dont really know why Im getting this error over and over

thank you for your help i will be really grateful

Comment: It's God's way of telling you that splash screens are evil. http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

res/layout/splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/YOUR_IMAGE_WIHOUT_EXTENSION"
    >
</LinearLayout>
```

This is what you are missing. The reason is, setContentView(R.layout.splash) is looking for an layout in your layout folder. For you to put the image as splash screen , this approach you need to put your image file into a `drawable` folder

Answer (score 1):

> the image is already there in drawable-hdpi folder in lower case as png extension

It sounds like `splash` is a `drawable`. `setContentView()` takes a `layout` which would be an xml file in your `layout` folder that may contain the `Image` you want to show. The app is looking in the `resources` for a `layout` file with id that matches `splash.xml` which it obviously won't find.

Answer (score 0):

The method `setContentView()` accepts a layout, so you can define the next layout `splash.xml` using your splash image and save it in `res/layout/splash.xml` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash" />
```